# Gem Issues with rbenv and bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I ahve rbenv installed with Ruby 1.9.3-p374 and I gem installed bundler.

I then set up a project diretory and set a .ruby-version file within to choose my 1.9.3 ruby version and then added a gemfile with some gems like compass etc. I then ran `bundle install --path vendor` and it installed.

If I then run `bundle show` I get this:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.2.3)
  * chunky_png (1.2.7)
  * compass (0.12.2)
  * fssm (0.2.10)
  * sass (3.2.5)
  * susy (1.0.5)
```

and if I run `gem list` I get this:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.2.3)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
```

How do I get them to all work together. I want the local project gems like compass etc to be installed into the vendor directory like they are but when I cd into my project directory and run a compass watch command I get `-bash: compass: command not found`

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running gems from your vendor bundle (instead of local gems), you should use `bundle exec`:

```
~/project$ bundle exec compass watch
```

If you want to run Compass directly, you'll have to install it on your system (local gems) using either vanilla `bundle install` or simply `gem install compass`. (In that case, you might sometimes run into a conflict of gem versions, Gemfile vs. called from system)

Comment: Brilliant! Is there a way I can get it to always bundle exec when called from within that project?

Comment: @rctneil I don't know of any obvious way to do that, no, the reason why I generally install mine locally to run the command lazily ;o) 

Is there a reason why you need to run them from your vendor bundle?